# Dialogflow - Can't save response with only media content

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-home, google-assist-api, google-smart-home

I want to set up a response which plays an mp3 file in response to invocation.

The only way I managed to get this to work is of I add a simple response and suggestion_chips.

When I try to save only the media content I get an error "Errors in 'Default Welcome Intent' intent: Google Assistant simple_response, suggestion_chips should be added to intent".

What is the correct way to set up a response that will play an mp3 file without a text response and suggestion_chips?

This does not work:

[image: This does not work:]

This works:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A MediaResponse must also have a simple text response or SSML response associated with it.

Comment: Is there a way to send empty text response?  Or the app won't get approved

Comment: You can send SSML, which may include silence or an empty response, but this would not fit best practices.